# Basic installations to setup rails application on ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, installation

I'm using a micro instance of ec2 for learning and testing purpose of my rails application as i never used ec2 in past. I created the account and was able to ssh. 
so when i do
$pwd
/home/ubuntu

Now did an scp and the project was imported. I'm unable to access ec2 instance through web. I looked around the web and found that the ports should be opened.

```
        ~$ netstat -anp | grep LISTEN
        (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
        tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
        tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
        tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
        tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
        unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7958     -                   /var/run/acpid.socket
        unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7726     -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
        unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6185     -                   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
        unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40164    -                   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
        unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6374     -                   /run/udev/control
```

$netstat -ln | grep 8080 
gives no response

When i do

```
        $curl -v xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        * About to connect() to xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 80 (#0)
        *   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xxx...
        * Connection refused
        * couldn't connect to host
        * Closing connection #0
        curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

What are the other basic installations to be done. As i see apache needs to be installed but would look for more clarity over this.

EDIT: Ruby,rails,rvm are installed and the sample app is running..

Comment: did you install ruby, rails and all other dependencies and configured the server and start it?

Comment: yes ..i installed it...and the sample app is running on the server using webrick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to start thin/webrick on port 80. using

```
    rvmsudo thin start -p 80 -d
```

So now the server is up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a security group for your instance in the AWS management console to open port 80. Here is a basic tutorial: http://cloud.lib.wfu.edu/blog/tech/2010/09/28/managing-firewall-rules-on-amazon-ec2-servers/

Also make sure Webrick runs on port 80, it defaults to 8080 or 3000.